# Implementation of a cavitation model

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, physics

### Problem formulation

Hi,

I'm following [this reference](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0643549.pdf) and I am trying to reproduce Fig. 19:
[image: Graph over closure time that I'm trying to reproduce]

The problem concerns an underwater shockwave, which hits the water-surface and produces a cavitation region. The reference is concerned with computing the dynamics of how the cavitation region collapses. If I understand the formalism correctly the problem is the following:

First solve the implicit equation
$$\exp\left(d/k\right) = 1 + d/k + P_a /\left(\rho g k\right)$$
for $d$, and then use $d$ to compute the cavitation time
$$T_c/\theta = \frac{2P_0}{\rho g\left(d + k\right) + P_a}.$$

The relevant definitions are
$$k = \frac{c \theta}{2 \cos\beta} = \frac{c \theta R}{2 D_b}$$
where $c = 1500$ m/s and $\rho = 1000$ kg/m3 is the water's speed of sound and density respectively.

$$\theta = W^{1/3} K_{\theta} \left(\frac{W^{1/3}}{R}\right)^{\alpha_{\theta}}$$
is the shocks time decay scale. $W$ is the mass of the explosive charge, and $K_{\theta}$ and $\alpha_\theta$ are empirical constants (given in code snippet).

The shock peak pressure is very similar
$$P_0 = K_p\left(\frac{W^{1/3}}{R}\right)^{\alpha_{p}}$$
where $K_{p}$ and $\alpha_p$ are empirical constants (given in code snippet). Note that $P_a$ is the atmospheric pressure.

The problem geometry looks like the following (note that the lengths $R$ and $d$ are defined here):
[image: System setup]

### Attempt at solution

Seems straightforward enough. I can use NSolve to solve the implicit equation, and then just plug in the value to compute the cavitation closure time. However, for the life of my I do not obtain the asymptotic behaviour in the attached figure. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
(*Parameters*)
Kp = 52.4;
\[Alpha]p = 1.13;
K\[Theta] = 0.084;
\[Alpha]\[Theta] = -0.23;

w = 50.0;
Db = 50.0;
\[Rho] = 1000.0;
g = 9.81;
c = 1500.0;
Patm = 101325.0;

DepthCavitationClosure[w_, Db_, Rh_, Kp_, \[Alpha]p_, 
  K\[Theta]_, \[Alpha]\[Theta]_, Patm_, \[Rho]_, g_, c_] := 
 Module[{k, \[Theta], P0, R, depth, Tc},
  R = Sqrt[Db^2 + Rh^2];
  P0 = Kp (w^(1/3)/R)^\[Alpha]p*10^6;
  \[Theta] = w^(1/3)*K\[Theta] (w^(1/3)/R)^\[Alpha]\[Theta]*10^-3;
  k = (c \[Theta] R)/(2 Db);
  solution = 
   NSolve[Exp[d/k] == 1 + d/k + Patm/(\[Rho] g k) && d >= 0, d];
  depth = d /. solution;
  Tc = \[Theta]* (2 (P0))/(\[Rho] g (k + depth) + Patm) ;
  {Tc}
  ]
depthTable = ParallelTable[
   {Rh, Flatten[
      DepthCavitationClosure[w, Db, Rh, Kp, \[Alpha]p, 
       K\[Theta], \[Alpha]\[Theta], Patm, \[Rho], g, c]][[1]]}
   , {Rh, 0, 1000, 10}];
ListPlot[depthTable]

Rh = 50;
DepthCavitationClosure[w, Db, Rh, Kp, \[Alpha]p, K\[Theta], \[Alpha]\
\[Theta], Patm, \[Rho], g, c]
```

Comment: The problem is likely to lie with your understanding of the model or the physics, rather than with your code, which works. Helping you with the former is difficult without a close reading of the paper you reference, but strangers on the Internet may not have time to do that for you.

Comment: I think UERD is plotting $t$ versus $R_h$ whereas you have plotted $T_C$ vs $R_h$.  Page 17 of the report defines $t$ as the time after shock-wave arrival at the surface, so we probably have $t = \sqrt{D_b^2+R_h^2}/c + T_C$.  The dashed line in the figure is probably $\sqrt{D_b^2+R_h^2}/c$ vs $R_h$.  Some of your constants are in SI units.  I suspect UERD would be using ft-lbs-sec, so `w = 50.0; Db = 50.0; g = 32.174; \[Rho] = 62.4 / g; c = 5000.0; Patm =14.7*144.0;`.  Note that c=5000 ft/sec is my guess.

Comment: Correction:  UERD may have used `\[Rho] = 64.0 / g` for seawater.

Comment: @LouisB This give a curve with the right shape! Units are off by factor of ~1000 somewhere.

Comment: @MelaGo You may be plotting time in seconds. UERD plotted time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you all, this indeed answered my question. I'm not sure how I should mark the question as solved. LouisB could write an answer, should it be moved to another stack exchange (e.g. physics), or should it be deleted as off-topic?